# jQuery animate css borderColor not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have a google map and when pressing a marker a infoBox opens, AND one div on a list of objects gets `.style.borderColor="#FFF";`

On `mouseout` of that infoBox I want it to go back to `border-color:#000;`

This works with javascript/jQuery

```
document.getElementById("rank_" + data.id).style.borderColor="#000"; //works good
$("#rank_" + data.id).css({borderColor: '#000'}); // also works good
```

this doesn't work

```
$("#rank_" + data.id).animate({ "border-color": "#000" }, 600);
//or
$("#rank_" + data.id).animate({ borderColor: "#000" }, 600);
//tried also this wich works but without animation
$("#rank_" + data.id).css({borderColor: '#000'}).animate({ borderColor: "#000" }, 900);
```

Any ideas on what I am missing?
simplified example **[here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKtjn)**

Comment: Like Djave has mentioned, jQuery.animate()  does not support colour animation. This is mentioned in their docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: You could toggle a class instead

Comment: Thanks rlemon and Djave, i see now also it doesn't animate colour :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One alternative is to use just CSS:
I use #one from your codepen example, but this should apply to the class of the div(s) you have.

```
#one {
    border:3px #0F0 solid;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGIhu

Answer (score 5):

jQuery doesn't support colour animation, I'd recommend a little plugin like 
http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Edit: as mentioned by @Ghillied, if you can be sure most targeted browsers support them, CSS3 transitions are probabaly a better solution all round! @Rikard has a nice example of this in his answer as well.

Otherwise, the bitstorm plugin really is very small in filesize, and would always be my preference for compatability (as my clients are depressingly stuck in browser stoneage)

Comment: Perhaps *jQuery* doesn't support color animation, but it looks like [*jQuery UI* does](http://jqueryui.com/animate/). Might be a good recommendation

Comment: You could also mention `CSS3` transitions and animations. Even though the answer is correct, it is quite opinion-based.

Comment: Yes, you don't want to load all of jQuery UI if you aren't going to use 99% of it though.

Comment: @BillCriswell: When you go to the site and download it, you have the ability to customize your download to only get the things you need.

Comment: Oh, I know. I'm not sure if you can *just* get the color animation part, though. I'm taking a look at the download page and I'm assuming you'd need "Core" and "Effects Core". The plugin above is way smaller.

Comment: @BillCriswell: Gotcha. Guess it will boil down to whether or not the OP will find more of jQuery UI useful enough to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and looking at my problem! (+1)

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery UI:

```
$("#rank_" + data.id).animate({ borderColor: "#000" }, 600);
```

http://jqueryui.com/animate/#default
Cross Browser rlz!